# Where is the best place to ask for a sanity-check on a UML diagram?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've built a UML diagram that's gotten fairly complex, and I'd like the community to "sanity-check" it for me.  My first instinct that codereview.stackexchange.com is the right place to ask for such things, but I thought it would be sensible to check first.

Is codereview the right place to ask for a review of a UML diagram?  Or is this better suited to programmers?

Comment: You might try asking on Codereview's meta as well as Programmers Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question, and the answer is *probably* Code Review.

I've asked a [similar question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/are-class-hierarchies-on-topic) on Meta Programmers, and [Mark's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/25936) makes sense:

> Posting a picture of a UML diagram and asking for critiques is way too specific and unlikely to help other people in the future, and I would say in general code/diagram critiques are off-topic.
>
> Code Review.SE is currently unique on the network in its focus on helping people with very localized, non-generalizable problems like this: I'm not totally convinced it's on-topic there, but I can definitely see why people would think that.

The [top voted answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/78/4673) on [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/should-design-questions-be-on-topic-here) on Meta Code Review seems to agree, but the other two answers do not, and are also positively scored (sometimes it's extremely hard to understand Meta). And of course the [Code Review FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) says that "Higher-level architecture and design of software systems" questions are off topic, and [this Meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/where-do-high-level-architecture-and-design-questions-go) points to Programmers for those.

It appears we're stuck in a loop, UML diagram reviews appear to be somewhere in the middle, but don't fit definitively on either site. Personally I think Code Review is the more suitable site, and the best course of action here would be to make a case for your question on Meta Code Review. If the Code Review community decides that UML diagram reviews are off topic, ping me in chat, I'd love to help re-start the discussion on Meta Programmers.

Comment: Did start a discussion at http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/539/9086 but doesn't seem to be generating any response at all, sadly.