# Questions on UML and other modeling languages

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, scope

What is the best place on Stack Exchange to ask specific questions about the proper use of notations used in UML and other modeling languages?

This question might seem like a possible duplicate of the following question: [Where is the best place to ask for a sanity-check on a UML diagram?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134334/where-is-the-best-place-to-ask-for-a-sanity-check-on-a-uml-diagram). But please note that I am not interested in getting an entire UML diagram reviewed. Rather, I am looking to ask specific questions about how to build software architectural or design models using UML or other modeling notations, with concrete examples at hand.

A simple example of one such question would be (and I am not expecting answers) -

> "When would one use a return message in a sequence diagram in UML?"

Or at least something to that degree. Of course, there should be more detail with example UML sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions on particular UML tools are on-topic at Stack Overflow. Questions on UML notation in general are a better fit for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (though one of their mods should weigh in on this).

Comment: In general, questions on UML are closed/deleted much less often on Programmers than other questions. Of course, "stupidest UML diagram" will still get closed.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the the OMG doesn't have a specific user community that you can approach however UML Modeling tools like Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems have very active and helpful communities that would be more than happy to answer any question you have on notations.

Main Site:
[Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com)

Their forum has a dedicated area to UML Processes:
[Sparx Systems Forum](http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php)

And their Community Site: 
[Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect Community Site](http://community.sparxsystems.com/)